# feature encoding for numerical features that depend on binary feature

Tags: classification, feature-engineering

I am working on a bounding box localisation problem where I need to detect whether a particular object is in an image, and if it is, I need to regress the coordinates of the bounding box. Currently, the labels of the data are encoded as [x,y, width, height] where (x,y) is the coordinate of the top left corner of the bounding box when the object is present. When the object is not present, all 4 features are set to NaN. So far, I have added another binary feature that is zero when the object is not present and one when the object is present.

My question is, what do I do with the 4 numerical features when the object is not present? I cannot leave them as NaNs because the 5 feature vector (binary + 4 numerical / NaN) needs to go into a differentiable loss function. Since the coordinates and dimensions of the bounding box are all positive, I was wondering if setting all 4 numerical values to a large negative number would work, but I am not sure.

Comment: if you control the loss function, you can take account of non-existent objects explicitly in the loss function and leave the values as NaN, else use coords outside the image dimensions

Comment: What should I set the loss to if the true label is all nans and the predicted label is not? Just some arbitrary large value?

Comment: You can use the maximum value the loss can take., If this is not known, then any sufficiently large value

Comment: Actually, my model does not predict NaN values since it is a CNN on image input, so I am not sure what I would predict in the 4 numerical coordinates when the object is not present to compare to NaNs.